# I need regex for bank routing number starts with 01 to 12 or 21 to 32 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this below regex to check 01 to 12 and hardcoded 21 to 32 to validate. Looking for better solution without hardcoding.

^(?=(?:[0][0-9]|1[0-2])|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32)\d{9}$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add sample test cases

Comment: Try [`^(?=(?:[0][1-9]|[13][0-2]|[2][0-9]))\d{9}$`](https://regex101.com/r/N1Y4Gw/1)

Comment: Thanks @User863. First two digits should be between 01 - 12 or 21-32. I don't know how to validate both options ( 01 - 12 or 21-32) together like 123456789 is correct, 223456789 is correct, 143456789 is incorrect, 373456789 is incorrect. can you explain me your regex

Comment: Seems the regex suits well for your test cases. You can find a better explanation at the right top of the above link.

Answer (score 1):

See if as simple as below caters to your need:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|2[1-9]|3[0-2])$/
```

If leading 0 is optional, you can make it to:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|2[1-9]|3[0-2])$/
```

Haven't tested it completely, but I'm sure you'll get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer zest. But I'm just validating first two digits. First two digits should be between 01 - 12 or 21-32. I don't know how to validate both options ( 01 - 12 or 21-32) together like 123456789 is correct, 223456789 is correct, 143456789 is incorrect, 373456789 is incorrect.

Comment: In that case, you can simply remove $ at the end.

/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|2[1-9]|3[0-2])/